# Laravel. Use scope() in models with relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two related models: `Category` and `Post`.

The `Post` model has a `published` scope (method `scopePublished()`).

When I try to get all categories with that scope:

```
$categories = Category::with('posts')->published()->get();
```

I get an error:

> Call to undefined method `published()`

**Category:**

```
class Category extends \Eloquent
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->HasMany('Post');
    }
}
```

**Post:**

```
class Post extends \Eloquent
{
   public function category()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('Category');
   }


   public function scopePublished($query)
   {
       return $query->where('published', 1);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 247, accepted):

You can do it inline:

```
$categories = Category::with(['posts' => function ($q) {
  $q->published();
}])->get();
```

You can also define a relation:

```
public function postsPublished()
{
   return $this->hasMany('Post')->published();
   // or this way:
   // return $this->posts()->published();
}
```

and then:

```
//all posts
$category->posts;

// published only
$category->postsPublished;

// eager loading
$categories->with('postsPublished')->get();
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you want to ONLY get where you have published posts: `Category::whereHas('posts', function ($q) { $q->published(); })->get();`

Comment: @tptcat yes. Also can be `Category::has('postsPublished')` in this case

Comment: Clean question, clean answer!

Comment: What if the query scope has a parameter?