# Laravel queryScope

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I created a queryScope

```
public function scopeCtmpActive($query)
{
    return $query->where('ctmp_active', 'y');
}
```

Then I replace following line

```
$customtemplates_collection = Auth::user()->customtemplates->where('ctmp_active', 'y')->sortByDesc('ctmp_id');
```

with

```
$customtemplates_collection = Auth::user()->customtemplates->ctmpActive()->sortByDesc('ctmp_id');
```

And I am getting following FatalErrorException

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::ctmpActive()
```

> How am I suppose to use a query exception with a relationship?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel. Use scope() in models with relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178315/laravel-use-scope-in-models-with-relation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name implies, "query" scopes are for reusable, common "query" constraints.

```
$customtemplates_collection = Auth::user()->customtemplates;
```

This returns a collection. You are getting **all** "customtemplates" that belong to the authenticated user. Then, Laravel is nice in that the Collection class allows for a nice way to filter out results, which is why the next part works:

```
$customtemplates_collection = Auth::user()->customtemplates->where('ctmp_active', 'y');
```

You are using PHP. Not MySQL. To emphasize, you are getting every single "customtemplates" that belongs to the user, and then using (PHP) Laravel Collection's `where` method to go through each one and filter out the results. You are **not** adding a where clause to the query. That's why the above works.

However, query scopes are for query constraints so they need to happen during the query, not after. What you probably want is something like this:

```
$customtemplates_collection = Auth::user()->customtemplates()->ctmpActive()->orderBy('ctmp_id', 'desc')->get();
```

When you add the paranthesis after `customtemplates()`, you are invoking the `customtemplates` method. In this case, I'm assuming it's a HasMany relationship so it'll return a `HasMany` instance. Then basically, it uses PHP's magic method (`__call`) to build the query builder so each method after that is essentially prepping the database query. Then, when you're finished building the query, you call `get` to fetch the results.

Comment: Yes this makes sense, but my usual difficulty is to identify what is going to return collection and what is going to return query resultset