# Laravel 5.2 Moving Query to Model from Controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hi so I have this large query for a search form, And I am just wondering how I would go about moving this into the Model, I have read up on Query Scopes and so on but this is a lot more complex than just searching 1 table for 1 field and I am just so lost, Any help is appreciated!

```
public function index()
{
    $input = Request::all();
    $date = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMinute(30);
    $query = User::rightJoin('user_profiles', 'users.id', '=', 'user_profiles.user_id');

    if (isset($input ['minAge']) && $input['minAge']) {
        $minAge = $input['minAge'];
        $maxDate = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subYears($minAge)->endOfDay();
    }

    if (isset($input ['maxAge']) && $input['maxAge']) {
        if ($input['maxAge'] < $input['minAge']) {
            $maxAge = $input['minAge'];
        }
        else {
            $maxAge = $input['maxAge'];
        }
        $minDate = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subYears($maxAge + 1);
    }

    if (isset($input['u']) && $input['u'])
        $query->where('users.username', '=', $input['u']);
    if (isset($input['p'])  && $input['p'])
        $query->where('user_profiles.postcode', '=', $input ['p']);
    if (isset($input['o1']) && $input['o1'])
        $query->where('users.last_online','>=',$date);
    if (isset($input['o2']) && $input['o2'])
        $query->whereNotNull('user_profiles.avatar');
    if (isset($input ['o3']) && $input['o3'])
        $query->orderBy('users.type', 'ASC');
    if (isset($input ['minAge']) && $input['minAge'])
        $query->whereBetween('user_profiles.dob', [$minDate, $maxDate]);
    if (isset($input ['g']))
        $query->whereIn('user_profiles.gender',$input ['g']);

    $query->orderBy('users.last_online', 'DESC');
    $users = $query->paginate(1);
    return view('view', compact('users'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this way. Accept $input as parameter in the function in User model.

In User model, add the following code.

```
public static function allUsers($input)
{
    $date = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMinute(30);
    $query = User::rightJoin('user_profiles', 'users.id', '=', 'user_profiles.user_id');

    if (isset($input ['minAge']) && $input['minAge']) {
        $minAge = $input['minAge'];
        $maxDate = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subYears($minAge)->endOfDay();
    }

    if (isset($input ['maxAge']) && $input['maxAge']) {
        if ($input['maxAge'] < $input['minAge']) {
            $maxAge = $input['minAge'];
        }
        else {
            $maxAge = $input['maxAge'];
        }
        $minDate = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subYears($maxAge + 1);
    }

    if (isset($input['u']) && $input['u'])
        $query->where('users.username', '=', $input['u']);
    if (isset($input['p'])  && $input['p'])
        $query->where('user_profiles.postcode', '=', $input ['p']);
    if (isset($input['o1']) && $input['o1'])
        $query->where('users.last_online','>=',$date);
    if (isset($input['o2']) && $input['o2'])
        $query->whereNotNull('user_profiles.avatar');
    if (isset($input ['o3']) && $input['o3'])
        $query->orderBy('users.type', 'ASC');
    if (isset($input ['minAge']) && $input['minAge'])
        $query->whereBetween('user_profiles.dob', [$minDate, $maxDate]);
    if (isset($input ['g']))
        $query->whereIn('user_profiles.gender',$input ['g']);

    $query->orderBy('users.last_online', 'DESC');
    $users = $query->paginate(1);
    return $users;
}
```

Then in your Controller, simply update the following.

With static,

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::allUsers(Request::all());
    return view('view', compact('users'));
}
```

Alternatively,

```
public function index()
{

    $user = new User;
    $user->allUsers(Request::all());
    return view('view', compact('users'));
}
```

Once you have done it this way, you can easily start to use smaller scopes. To use sample scope, you may checkout this [Laravel. Use scope() in models with relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178315/laravel-use-scope-in-models-with-relation)

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Ah i Just get an error Non-static method App\Search::allUsers() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context ( i have put this in its own search model and controller since my last post hence the Search.)

Comment: Thanks again man, It worked, Just a quick fix where you have $users = User::allUsers(Request::all); its missing the () after all like so (Request::all());

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Thanks for correction. I have also updated the main post for future references for others. Cheers