# Get scope from multilevel relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

**Description of problem:**
So I have tried a lot of things now and I can't get it to work. With the current code I get "Call to a member function thisyear() on null" on the line "

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    $rows = SeatRows::all();
    return view('seating.index')
            ->withRows($rows);
}
```

**SeatRows Model:**

```
class SeatRows extends Model {

    protected $table = 'seat_rows';

    public function seats() {
        return $this->hasMany('Seats', 'row_id');
    }

}
```

**Seats Model:**

```
class Seats extends Model {

    protected $table = 'seats';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'slug',
        'row_id',
    ];

    function row() {
        return $this->hasOne('SeatRows', 'id', 'row_id');
    }

    function reservation() {
        return $this->hasOne('SeatReservation', 'seat_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

**SeatReservation Model:**

```
class SeatReservation extends Model {

    function seat() {
        return $this->hasOne('Seats', 'id', 'seat_id');
    }

    function reservedfor() {
        return $this->hasOne('User', 'id', 'reservedfor_id');
    }

    function reservedby() {
        return $this->hasOne('User', 'id', 'reservedby_id');
    }

    public function scopeThisYear($query) {
        return $query->where('year', '=', \Setting::get('SEATING_YEAR'));
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@foreach($rows as $row)

    <li class="seat-row">
        <ul class="seat-row-{{$row->slug}}">
            @foreach($row->seats as $seat)
                <li class="seat @if($seat->reservation->thisyear()->count() > 0) @if($seat->reservation->thisyear()->status->id == 1) seat-reserved @elseif($seat->reservation->thisyear()->status->id == 2) seat-tempreserved @endif @if(Sentinel::getUser()->id == $seat->reservation->thisyear()->first()->reservedfor->id and $seat->reservation->thisyear()->first()->status->id == 1) seat-yours @endif  @endif @if(Request::segment(3) == $seat->slug) active @endif ">
                    <p>
                        @if($seat->reservation->thisyear()->count() == 0)
                            <a href="{{ route('seating-show', $seat->slug) }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Available">{{ $seat->name }}</a>
                        @elseif(Sentinel::getUser()->id == $seat->reservation->thisyear()->reservedfor->id and $seat->reservation->thisyear()->status->id == 1)
                            <a href="{{ route('seating-show', $seat->slug) }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This seat is reserved for you!">{{ $seat->name }}</a>
                        @elseif($seat->reservation->thisyear()->status->id == 1)
                            <a href="{{ route('seating-show', $seat->slug) }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Reserved for: {{ User::getUsernameAndFullnameByID($seat->reservation->thisyear()->reservedfor->id) }}">{{ $seat->name }}</a>
                        @elseif($seat->reservation->thisyear()->status->id == 2)
                            <a href="{{ route('seating-show', $seat->slug) }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Temporary Reserved By: {{ User::getUsernameAndFullnameByID($seat->reservation->thisyear()->reservedfor->id) }}">{{ $seat->name }}</a>
                        @else
                            {{ $seat->name }}
                        @endif
                    </p>
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Please could you also show your relationships for `reservedfor` and `status`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something looks wonky to me in your relationship and query definitions.  It looks to me like Seats hasMany SeatReservations (one for each year) not hasOne.

Also, your code probably doesn't work because a particular seat may have no reservations in which case you'll never get to `thisyear()` to check the count.

I think you need to change how you call your relation.  See: [Laravel. Use scope() in models with relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178315/laravel-use-scope-in-models-with-relation)

Something like this might work:

```php
class Seats extends Model {
    function reservationThisYear() {
        return $this->hasMany('SeatReservation', 'seat_id', 'id')->thisYear();
    }

}
```

Also, don't mix `->count()` and `->id`.  Count only exists on an array of returns.  A hasOne would return null if it doesn't exist not with a count of 0.  Since we are now using a hasMany though, you could use `$seat->reservationThisYear->count()`, but you'll need to use `$seat->reservationThisYear[0]->reservedfor->id`.

Note: Using `$seat->reservationThisYear[0]->reservedfor->id` will result in a PHP error if the reservedfor relation does not match any rows.  (IE The seat is not reserved.)

Comment: This actually work real well! Thanks for the solution, I guess I was to tired to think yesterday.

Also thanks for the tips! Its been a year since last I worked on this project. :)