# Laravel 5.5 pivot join to get pivot values with main MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, pivot

I'm trying to join a pivot table on a MySQL query. Basically I'm selecting the users, where one user has multiple sub categories.

So in essence with my "sub_categories relationship, one user has many sub categories. But because I am using RAW select, I cannot select / use the relationships. Instead I have to use a join.

This is my sub_categories table

```
    Column  Type    Comment
    id  int(10) unsigned Auto Increment  
    main_category_id    int(10) unsigned [0]     
    category_name   varchar(100)     
    created_at  timestamp NULL   
    updated_at  timestamp NULL
```

and this is my pivot table

```
    Column  Type    Comment
    user_id int(10) unsigned     
    sub_category_id int(10) unsigned
```

This is my SQL query

```
$users= DB::table('users')
    ->select('users.*', 'user_options.*', DB::raw('
        branches.*,
        professional_profiles.tags,
        ' . $lat . '  AS latpoint,  
        ' . $lng . ' AS longpoint,
        ' . $radius . ' AS radius,
        ' . $measurement_number . ' AS distance_unit,
        (
            ' . $measurement_number . ' * DEGREES(
                ACOS(
                    COS(RADIANS(' . $lat . '))
                    * COS(RADIANS(branches.lat))
                    * COS(RADIANS(' . $lng . ' - branches.lng))
                    + SIN(RADIANS(' . $lat . '))
                    * SIN(RADIANS(branches.lat))
                )
            )
        ) AS distance
        '), 'users.id AS id')
        ->leftJoin('branches', 'users.branch_id', '=', 'branches.id')
        ->leftJoin('user_options', 'user_options.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->leftJoin('professional_profiles', 'professional_profiles.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('user_options.professional', '>', 0)
        ->where('users.branch_id', '>', 0)
        ->where(function ($x) use ($term) {
            $x->where('branches.branch_name', 'like', '%' . $term . '%')
                ->orWhere('branches.branch_city', 'like', '%' . $term . '%')
                ->orWhere('users.firstname', 'like', '%' . $term . '%')
                ->orWhere('users.lastname', 'like', '%' . $term . '%')
                ->orWhere('professional_profiles.tags', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
        })
        ->having('distance', 'orderBy('distance', 'asc')
        ->limit(50)
        ->get();
```

And this is my result:

```
    [
        {
            id: 4,
            profile_id: 2,
            branch_id: 3,
            prefix: "dr",
            firstname: "SWK1",
            lastname: "Doe",
            email: "swk1@gmail.com",
            mobile_no: "811692244",
            password: "$2y$10$LzkPwc2TZu/.UzB.0mYJ",
            avatar: "123.jpg",
            remember_token: "wF33ShLirtvS3mIYJpmg5skVVoohGJCS7v",
            created_at: "2017-10-12 09:32:05",
            updated_at: "2017-10-12 09:32:05",
            provider: null,
            provider_id: null,
            user_id: 4,
            profile_administrator: 0,
            branch_administrator: 0,
            professional: 1,
            branch_name: "Swakopmund 1",
            branch_address_1: "14 Backer St",
            branch_address_2: null,
            branch_city: "Swakopmund",
            branch_state: null,
            branch_zip: "9000",
            branch_country: "NA",
            branch_phone: "77777",
            main_image: null,
            lat: -22.67,
            lng: 14.53,
            description: "Swakopmund 1",
            tags: "Doctors,Dietician,General Practitioner",
            latpoint: "-22.5608807",
            longpoint: "17.0657549",
            radius: 500,
            distance_unit: "111.045",
            distance: 260.210154298872
        }
    ]
```

So essentially the question would be to join the sub_categories table on the users table, by making use of the values set by the pivot table, without relying on the eloquent relationships table but rather by making use of a SQL.

Since **one user has many sub_categories,** it would be great to return the sub_categories as an array value joined on the main SQL query.

Comment: I have exactly same situation and I have used scope and with() methods to get array of sub category associated with Users. I will find my code and post meanwhile you can Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178315/laravel-use-scope-in-models-with-relation

Answer (score 1):

I had similar situation and I [Query Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#query-scopes) along with my pivot table for one to many relation. In my situation, User has multiple groups and I need to fetch those data along with user object without extra query or without JOINs.
See `Query scope` and one to many and **many to many with pivot on Laravel Doc.**

If you want to fetch data using pivote table, here is the example 
**User Model:**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;


    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'username', 'password',
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group', 'user_groups', 
          'user_id', 'group_id');
    }
    public function scopeDetail($query)
    {
        return $query->with('groups');
    }
}
```

**Group Model:**

```
class Group extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'dn', 'cn', 'description',
    ];
}
```

In above user model, see `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group','user_groups', 'user_id', 'group_id');`, where user_groups is my pivot table which defines the relationship between users and group. `group_id` and `user_id` are the fields in pivote table.

Now Fetching data (on controller) using above architechture:

```
User::where(.....)->detail()->first();
```

where `detail()` is my scope defined in User model as `scopeDetail`. Note: `scope` prefix must be attached. This will give you the user with all the groups that user belongs to in array, so whenever you view your data in JSON you can see the structure in proper way.

Using above method, my **user** object has all the groups that user belongs to.

**Extra**
If your user model(users) related to other models too then you can include all those by defining scope on model class as

```
............
//..............
    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Profile', 'user_id');
    }
    public function data1()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Data1', 'user_id');
    }
    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group', 'user_groups', 
          'user_id', 'group_id');
    }
    //Defining query scope................
    public function scopeDetail($query)
    {
        return $query->with('groups','profile','data1');
        //to fetch user with this scope use User::where(.....)->detail()->get(); notice there is not scope prefix while using the scope
    }
........
........
```

Comment: Hey, its so kind of you for your detailed reply. I will try the method this evening and post back. Thanx so much.

Comment: Going craxy >> I've noticed that I've overlooked something which could have saved me a lot of time. Yikes! I'll post back ;)

Comment: This is example how i fetch all groups belongs to an user using query scope. Always try to utilize Laravel Native features. Let me know if I can post code for your problem but its better if you solve your problem on your own.