# Laravel: Excluding filtering on many to many relation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have two models: Food and Equipment.
These two models are related by many to many relationship (also handled my Laravel Eloquent). So Food has some required equipment to prepare it.

I would like filter foods which contains all Equipment given on input and there is no any other Equipment for this food required. So in other words - when input Equipment is containing in Equipment related with certain Food.

---

### Idea presenting examples

For example I have sample Food called "Xyz cake". To prepare this food you need

- blender
- oven

Let's assume we have on input following Equipment:

- blender
- kitchen robot
- oven

In this case filtering script should take our Food into results because Equipment related with Food is fitting into input Equipment.

---

Another example: "Abc cake". Required Equipment:

- blender
- kitchen robot
- oven

Input Equipment:

- blender
- kitchen robot

In this case script should not take Food into results because to prepare Food there is also required oven, but oven isn't present in input Equipment.

---

### My current code

***$equipments*** variable is array containing ids of input Equipments.

```
$query = Food::query();
$query->join('equipments_foods', function ($join) use ($equipments) {
    $join->on('foods.id', '=', 'equipments_foods.food_id');
    $join->whereIn('equipments_foods.equipment_id', $equipments);
});
$results = $query->get();
```

This code is not working properly, because it is giving Foods which contains at least one Equipment from input Equipments.

Database is MySQL.

Please help me achieve properly working filtering.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use eager loading using `with()` and scoped query. something like `$users = User::with('podcasts')->get();` and if you have more than one relation then use scoped like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46732845/laravel-5-5-pivot-join-to-get-pivot-values-with-main-mysql-result/46733069#46733069

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching to find properly solution finally I managed to get it working using Laravel Query Builder.

I didn't think it was that easy.

```
$query = Food::query();
$query->where(function ($query) use ($inputEquipment) {
    $query->doesntHave('equipments');
    $query->orWhere(function ($query) use ($inputEquipment) {
        foreach ($inputEquipment as $equipmentId) {
            $query->whereHas('equipments', function ($query) use ($equipmentId) {
                $query->where('id', $equipmentId);
            });
        }
    });
});
$results = $query->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following works for your problem. Here's an SQL Fiddle to test with.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d04555/3

Basically, it flips the problem on it's head, and finds and excludes all foods using non-selected equipment.

```
SELECT f.*
FROM food f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM equipment e 
    INNER JOIN equipments_foods ef ON (e.id = ef.equipment_id)
    WHERE e.id NOT IN (1, 2, 3)
    AND f.id = ef.food_id
)
```

And then you may be able to create a model query scope to contain this logic. The following is an untested attempt at writing this using Laravel's query builder.

```
$foods = Food::usingEquipment($equipment)->get();

public function scopeUsingEquipment(Builder $query, array $equipment)
{
    return $query->whereNotExists(function ($query) use ($equipment) {
        $query->select(DB::raw(1))
            ->from('equipment')
            ->join('equipments_foods', 'equipment.id', '=', 'equipments_foods.equipment_id')
            ->whereIn('equipment.id', $equipment)
            ->whereRaw('food.id = equipments_foods.food_id');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will advice you use laravel's many to many pivot table.
Your Food model should look like this

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Food extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [ 'name'];

public function equipments(){

return $this>belongsToMany('App\equipment','food_equipment','food_id','equipment_id');

}

public function scopeRel($query){

return $query->with('equipments');
}

}

food_equipment is the pivot table, while food_id and equipment_id are fields in the pivot table.
This relationship ensures all equipments required to make different kinds of food is matched appropriately.

The scopeRel is a local scope that will return all the equipments needed to prepare the food in an array.

You can query the Model with.
Food::where('equipment_id', 1)->rel()->first();

Comment: Ok, thank you. But why there is "user_id" param in belongsToMany() relation method ? And also how can I handle more the one required equipment ?

Comment: @zyx4sdk the user_id was a mistake, I have edited it to food_id. The relationship defined in the Food model takes care of that.