# Laravel migration with relation

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration, relation

I am new with Laravel, so I do not know what exactly is this problem. So I will describe it in detail. First I have 2 table **Article** and **Comment**, with the relation 1-1, it means that an article can only have 1 comments.
The code is:

```
$article = Article::with('comments')
```

and the result is

[image]

and below is the attribute of comment I get in relation:

[image]

But now, I want the builder select only the article where the article's content length > its comment's content length. In MySQL statement, it is

```
"Select from articles a where length(a.content) > (Select length(c.content) from comments c where c.article_id = a.id)
```

I have tried with **raw** and **join** and it work. But I want to find out that can I do the same with "**with**" relation? How can I do this?

Comment: article's content length > its article's content length? doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Wreigh sorry, its comment's content length. It my fault

Comment: I think, your specification is technically wrong. `with` loads a relationship. But what you are trying to do is to *retrieve* a model based from its relations. `Article::with('comments')` means load all *articles* with its relative **comment**. I think it's better to use `where`s instead, don't you think?

Comment: Can you write the full code. i want  to get articles with the condition depended on its relation with comments 
( where length(article.content) > length(article.comment.content) )

Comment: do you want to get all the article where the length of article content is bigger than the length of comment content?

Comment: Yes, you right. I have tried with raw and join and it work. But i want to know can i do the same with (with) or not?

Comment: @Wregh gave you idea. Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178315/laravel-use-scope-in-models-with-relation) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> $article = Article::where(DB::raw('length(content)','>' ,DB::raw('Select length(content) from comments where article_id = id'))->with(['comments'])->get();

Comment: As i said in the question, i don't want to find the way with raw and join

Comment: but your query maybe not covered by eloquent function, and alternative you can using db raw or collection filter with define article and comment object. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-filter

Comment: No, please read my question. I knew i can use raw. I have used raw and success. But i want to find how another way (not use raw).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$articles = Article::with('comments')->get();

$onlyWithLongerContent = $articles->filter(function($article) {
    return strlen($article->content) > strlen($article->comments->content);
})->values();
```

I will try to think of another way, but this is one way of doing it.

Another way would probably be about building queries for that using join and where clauses.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be close to what i expected. But the problem is i want to Article::with('comments')->mycondition()->paginate(); So if i use get() then it can't be paginate because it is now collection. Paginate is only work with builder

Comment: if you want to paginate, I suggest that you use raw queries with query builder.

Comment: Hm, i have used it. (i have said in the question). I only want to find out if i can use "with" instead or not?

Comment: no you cant. `with` is used to eager load relationships; E.g., to eager load all comments related to articles. In your case, you're trying to filter the result of your model query, that's out of scope of `with` which manipulates or is focused on the *relationship* side.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
/**
 * Get the comments.
 *
 * @return 
 */
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasmany('App\Comments')->where('content', '!=', null);
}
```

Or

```
/**
 * Get the comments
 *
 * @return
 */
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Comments', 'App\Articles', 'id', 'article_id')->where('content', '!=', null);
}
```