# Laravel local scope:BadMethodExeption

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, eloquent

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model {
    public function scopeCompleted($query){
        return $query->where('completed',1);   
    }
```

When I call method:

```
App\Task::completed()
```

I get:

> BadMethodCallException with message 'Method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::completed does not exist.'

I created local scope, but i can't use method to search query.
And i called:

```
$task = App\Task::completed()->get();
```

same error!

Comment: Does the error message show where the exception occurred?

Comment: Similar question has been answered. You can find answer in:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178315/laravel-use-scope-in-models-with-relation][1]