# Using eloquent relation

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to understand how to effectively use Eloquent relationships to have some high level functions in the model.
I have a subscription app with 2 tables, 'users' and 'subscriptions'.
This is a legacy system so I cannot just change things in any way I want.

```
 Table users (model App\User)
 id
 email
 active (0/1)
 join_date
 address etc
 phone

 Table subscriptions (model App\Subscription)
 id
 user_id
 box_id (what the person is subscribed to get)
 amount
```

Users are marked active or not active.

I would like to have a static method on the Subscription model that will give me all the active subscriptions. This data is then fed into other parts of the application.

This is derived by joining subscriptions to users and filtering based on the `active` column.
The query is like this:

```
SELECT users.*, subscriptions.*
FROM subscriptions
JOIN users ON users.id = subscriptions.user_id
WHERE users.active = 1
```

Subscription model

```
class Subscription extends Model
{
    public static function allActive()
    {
        // This works except it doesn't use the eloquent relationship
        return static::where('users.active', 1)
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'subscriptions.user_id')
            ->select('users.*','subscriptions.*')
            ->get();
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

User model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    public function subscriptions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Subscription::class);
    }
}
```

I would use it like this:

```
$subscriptions = \App\Subscription::allActive()->toArray();
print_r($subscriptions);
```

I have 2 questions.

1. How do I rewrite the `allActive` function to use the relationship I already defined? Any solution should generate SQL with a JOIN.
2. In the returned data, how do I separate the columns from the two separate tables so that it is clear which table the data came from?

Comment: take a look at this, hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178315/laravel-use-scope-in-models-with-relation

Comment: and for debugging your collection better to use `dump($subscriptions)` or `dd($subscriptions)`, then you can see more detailed info

Answer (score 0):

Given the relationships you have wired up, to get only active subscriptions from the model class you will have to do it this way:

```
class Subscription extends Model
{
    public static function allActive()
    {
        $activeSubcriptions = Subscription::whereHas('user', function($query){
            $query->where('active', 1) //or you could use true in place of 1
        })->get();
        return $activeSubcriptions;
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Thats working with `closures` in Laravel, quite an efficient way of writing advanced eloquent queries.

In the callback function you will do pretty much anything with the $`query` object, its basically working on the User model since you mentioned it as the first parameter of the `->whereHas`

Note that that variable has to have **EXACTLY** the same name used in declaring the relationship

The above i suppose answers your first question, however its highly recommended that you do most of this logic in a controller file

To answer question 2, when you execute that `get()` it will return `Subscription` objects array so to access the info based on columns you will have to go like:

```
$subscriptions = \App\Subscription::allActive();

foreach($subscriptions as $subscription){
    $amount = $subscription->amount; //this you access directly since we working with the subscription object
    $box_id = $subscription->box_id;

    //when accessing user columns
    $email = $subscription->user->email; //you will have to access it via the relationship you created
    $address = $subscription->user->address;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. `Subscription->whereHas` doesn't look right. Did you mean `$this->whereHas`?

Comment: I did some testing on this. This solution works but it generates a separate query for each user rather than doing one query with a join.

Comment: that all depends with what you intended to do, but am pretty much sure your main question was answered . Cheers

Comment: There is a query in the original question. This solution does not produce that query. Rather, it creates numerous separate queries, one for each user. This is inefficient and not scalable. What happens when I have 10000 subscribers? As best as I can tell, there is no way to do what I am asking. i.e. use the relationship to generate a join query.