# Laravel - ORM where clause for eager loading

Tags: laravel, orm

Here my ORM that I'm running:

```
$developers = Developer::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')->with('programs')->get();
```

The model for Developer is this:

```
public function programs()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Program');
}
```

This is bringing back all the names from the Developer table not from the programs tables. How would I go about trying to get all the the program names instead of the developer names?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel. Use scope() in models with relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178315/laravel-use-scope-in-models-with-relation)

Comment: That didn't help. Close but wasn't the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like this:

```
$query = "hello";
$developers = Developer::whereHas('programs', function($q) use($query){
    $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%');
})->get();
```

It will help you!