# Issue with HasMany definition with scope

Tags: laravel, eloquent, scope, laravel-9

so I'm defining this function in a `Dosser` model :

```
    public function billingDocs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(BillingDoc::class);
    }

    public function regularInvoiceDocs()
    {
        return $this->billingDocs()->regularType();
    }
```

And in `BillingDoc` model :

```
    public function scopeRegularType(Builder $builder)
    {
        $builder->where('billing_type_id', BillingType::named('regular')->id);
    }
```

Now, if I call from a function in `Dossier` model `$this->regularInvoiceDocs` it returns an empty array. But if I call `$this->regularInvoiceDocs()->get()` it returns the desired items. Of course if I just call `$this->billingDocs` I have the desired items as well. I thought defining HasMany functions with scope conditions was fine? I use it a lot without issue, I don't understand what is happening here. Thanks ahead!

Comment: I'm confused. To [use a scope](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#utilizing-a-local-scope) you need to call `get()` on it, don't you?

Comment: Of course you need to use get to return a collection, else you are basically just executing the query without returning anything

Comment: So, I know you're confused, but it actually works perfectly. And it's so useful so you might want to use it. You're defined scoped relationships like that. See another example in that answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26178429/1928380

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was mistaken and the issue came from another part of my code. It was a test, and the function building `regularInvoiceDocs` relationship was called twice, once when it's empty and the second time when it should have returned a collection. But the relationship was cached from the first time. So, a simple `$dossier->refresh()` and everything works fine.