# use relations in scopes in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I Want To Use Relation Methods In Scopes But It Gives an Error.

Error:
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::members()`

Controller:
`$members = $book->MembersLoanedCurrentBook()->paginate(8);`

Scope:

```
public function scopeMembersLoanedCurrentBook(Builder $query): Builder
{
    return $query->members()->orderBy('return_date')->where('book_member.returned',false);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178315/laravel-use-scope-in-models-with-relation

Comment: @geertjanknapen No, my question is different

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your models are something akin to `User hasMany BookMember` and `Book has an attribute called` returned`, you can use Laravel's` with` query scope:

```
Users::with(['member_books', function ($q) => {
    $q->returned
})->get();
```

@geertjanknapen was right that this is a possible duplicate. You can achieve the same result using the methods from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178315/laravel-use-scope-in-models-with-relation).

What you are doing is defining a scope and in that scope querying a relationship for a specific property or value.

```
public function scopeMembersLoanedCurrentBook(Builder $query): Builder
{
    return $query->members()
                 ->orderBy('return_date')
                 ->whereHas(['book', function ($q) => {
                      $q->returned == false;
                 });
});
```

}

Without knowing the model structure and relationships, it's hard to write out an exact solution, but something along these lines should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't work with relations in scope, because your work with Builder $query.

```
public function scopeMembersLoanedCurrentBook(Builder $query): Builder
    {
        return $query->orderBy('return_date')
        ->where('returned',false);
    }
```

And

```
$members = $book->members()->MembersLoanedCurrentBook()->paginate(8);
```